# php upload image and documents like pdf,doc,ppt

Tags: php

hello all i have been working on a web page where users can upload images and applications like word file,ppt,pdf,excel file etc.. but i am not sure about my code can any one please suggest me a better and more secure way to deal with this . i want to do mime check not from the client side but from the server side . and also i want the maximum file size to be uploaded to be 7 mb .
this is my code can any one please suggest me anything

```
 $allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx","png","jpg","jpeg","gif");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["uploadpic"]["name"]));
if (($_FILES["uploadpic"]["type"] == "application/pdf") ||
($_FILES["uploadpic"]["type"] == "application/msword") || 
 ($_FILES["uploadpic"]["type"] 
 == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") ||  
 ($_FILES["uploadpic"]["type"] == "image/png") ||
   ($_FILES["uploadpic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") || 
   ($_FILES["uploadpic"]["type"] == "image/jpg") 
    && ($_FILES["uploadpic"]    ["size"] < 7340032) && 
   in_array($extension,  $allowedExts))
{
  if ($_FILES["uploadpic"]["error"] > 0)
  {
echo 'error';
exit;
  }
  else
  {
   $filetname=$_FILES ['uploadpic']['tmp_name'];
    $filename=$_FILES ['uploadpic']['name'];
   $insert=move_uploaded_file($filetname,"folder/$filename"); 
   $insertpostsandpic=mysql_query("insert into `database` (`id`,`name`,`date`) 
    values   ('$id','$filename','$time')");
     echo 'sucess'; exit;
     }
      } else{
   echo 'fail';
   exit;
      }
```

Comment: Is that working properly?

Comment: ya it is working but not for ppt files and also here the mime check is user side ..

Comment: user can upload a php file by changing it extention to png

Comment: can't see any checking for `ppt` files in your script..

Answer (score 0):

Create two arrays: one with accepted extensions and one with accepted mime types. Use `SplFileInfo::getExtension()` to get file extension.

I suggest the following code:

```
$accepted_mimes = array(
    'image/png',
    'application/pdf',
    'addyourown'
);
$accepted_extensions = array(
    'png',
    'pdf',
    'addyourown'
);
$max_file_size = 7*1000*1000;
$file = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

$obj = new SplFileInfo($file);
$extension = $obj->getExtension();
$mime = $obj->getType();
$size = $obj->getSize();

if(!in_array($extension, $accepted_extensions))
{
    echo 'Extension '. $extension .' not accepted';
}
if(!in_array($mime, $accepted_mimes))
{
    echo 'Extension '. $mime .' not accepted';
}
if($size > $max_file_size)
{
    echo 'File size exceeded maximum file size limit';
}
```